# ListView.separated() gives error when trying to delete item from it

Tags: flutter

hi everyone i'm new to flutter and have an list with two items whenever i try to delete last item with bottomSheet it gives error. I debug the code and after removing the last item from the list control starts to rebuild the ui and when it encounters the bottomSheet method it stopped and gives the following error

```
 The following RangeError was thrown building BottomSheet(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#35052], _InheritedTheme], state: _BottomSheetState#5503c):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

    package:test1/main.dart:24
  When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0 List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:149:60)
#1 List.elementAt (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:358:16)
#2 _MyAppState.build...
package:test1/main.dart:46
#3 _BottomSheetState.build
package:flutter/…/material/bottom_sheet.dart:212
#4 StatefulElement.build
```

and here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(
MyApp(),
);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State {
List list2 =
List.generate(2, (i) => new Item("name $i", false, Colors.red));
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final title = 'Long List';

return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    ),
    body: ListView.separated(
      itemCount: list2.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3) + 35,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[

                        !list2.elementAt(index).isColorAdded
                            ? InkWell(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Add to data",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                              )
                            : InkWell(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Remove from Data",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                  setState(() {
                                    list2.removeAt(index);
                                  });
                                },
                              ),

                        Divider(
                          color: Color(0xffDCDCDC),
                          thickness: 0.5,
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Remove Excercise",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            list2.removeAt(index);
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                });
          },
          title: Text('${list2[index].name}'),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Divider(
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

class Item {
String name;
bool isColorAdded;
var color;

Item(this.name, this.isColorAdded, this.color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code

1. You forgot to add `setState` when you `"Remove Excercise"`
2. If you remove all the items in the list you will also get an error because the list must contain at least one child, so add a check before rendering the list.